# View Pager - slide to next page programmatically with static variable

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, static

I would like to make a slide programmatically in my ViewPager.

My problem is, that the event to slide is called by a button that is placed inside of a fragment that is hold by the ViewPager.

I know about the code:

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(int index)
```

And now I my thought was to make the ViewPager variable public static to access it from the child fragment. 
But the static variable is not accessible from the child fragment.

How can I achieve this to make a slide by clicking on a button that is placed inside of a page?

Comment: Where do you have your Viewpager object which you want to make public? In the MainActivity or inside another fragment?

Comment: Inside of a Fragment. But I can change it to an activity that holds the viewpager if it is neesed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an `interface` to interact with your `ViewPager` via your `Activity` (or a `Fragment` hosted in said `Activity`) without exposing any fields.

Inside the `ViewPager` `Fragment`, create an `interface`:

```
public class FragmentInViewPager extends Fragment {

    private Callback mCallback;

    public interface Callback {
        void setViewPagerCurrentPage(int page);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        mCallback = (Callback) activity; 
        //NB: The above will throw ClassCastException if your Activity
        //Does not implement FragmentInViewPager.Callback
    }

    //To call it...
    int newPageNumber = 27;
    mCallback.setViewPagerCurrentPage(newPageNumber);
```

Have your `Activity` implement the `interface`, and from there interact with your `ViewPager` directly (if it is a variable in your `Activity`) or access it in one of your fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentInViewPager.Callback {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    //...
    @Override
    public void setViewPagerCurrentPage(int page) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
        //Or...if it is inside another Fragment...
        ViewPagerFragment frag = (ViewPagerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("view_pager_fragment_tag");
        if (frag != null) frag.getViewPager().setCurrentItem(page);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside your childFragment you have to get a reference to the Fragement which holds your Viewpager.

```
FragmentViewPager fragmentViewPager = (FragmentViewPager) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(yourTag);
```

Setting viewpager to public is sufficient. Then you can call

```
fragmentViewPager.viewpager.setCurrentItem(index);
```

Comment: You may be right, but in my own projects casting wasn't necessary for getting the FragmentManager.

Comment: I've found something interesting: If you use `android.app.Fragment` and call `getActivity()`, you'll get a Activity. Instead, if you use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, you'll get a FragmentActivity from where you can call `getSupportFragmentManager()`. So in this case, casting is only necessary for `android.app.Fragment`.