# getSupportFragmentManager() is not working on onCreateView() method of the fragment class.

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bundle

Goodevening. I have read several questions here in stackoverflow and some tutorial articles and site about fragments. I'm currently passing some data on the first fragment class to the second fragment class. But I've got some error on the part of transaction in the bundle, It says in the error that the method getSupportFragmentManager() method is undefined.

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, cblf).commit();
```

What is the bestway to fix this problem?
Anyways, here is my whole code,

```
package com.example.navigationdrawerexample;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CollegeBulletinFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    Button ccs;
    Button coe;
    Button coed;
    Button con;
    Button cba;
    Button cas;
    Button cihm;
    Button gn;
    public CollegeBulletinFragment(){   
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collegebulletin, container, false);

        gn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gn);
        ccs = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ccs);
        coe = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.coe);
        coed = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.coed);
        con = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.con);
        cba = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cba);
        cas = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cas);
        cihm = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cihm);

        gn.setOnClickListener(this);
        ccs.setOnClickListener(this);
        coe.setOnClickListener(this);
        coed.setOnClickListener(this);
        con.setOnClickListener(this);
        cba.setOnClickListener(this);
        cas.setOnClickListener(this);
        cihm.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String passingword = "";
        switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.ccs:
            passingword = "CCS";
            break;
        case R.id.coe:
            passingword = "COE";
            break;
        case R.id.gn:
            passingword = "GN";
            break;
        case R.id.coed:
            passingword = "COED";
            break;
        case R.id.con:
            passingword = "CON";
            break;
        case R.id.cba:
            passingword = "CBA";
            break;
        case R.id.cas:
            passingword = "CAS";
            break;
        case R.id.cihm:
            passingword = "CIHM";
            break;

        }

        CollegeBulletinListFragment cblf = new CollegeBulletinListFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("passingWord", passingword);
        cblf.setArguments(args);

         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, cblf).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error that the method getSupportFragmentManager() method is undefined

Because `getSupportFragmentManager()` method is not available in `Fragment` class it is in `FragmentActivity` so use `getActivity()` to access it.like:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, cblf).commit();
```

Comment: So I have to change my extending class above to `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: @JohnRannielSinel: No, see my edit answer. use `getActivity()`

Comment: @JohnRannielSinel: One more thing if u want to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` method then import Fragment from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: There is no avaiable method getSupportFragmentManager() at getActivity() method.

Comment: @JohnRannielSinel: Are you extending Activity or FragmentActivity in Activity in which adding Fragment?

Comment: I'm extending my class to Fragment class. I've got an error here, telling that the identifier cblf is not a fragment eventhough the class CollegeBulletinListFragment extends Fragment.

Comment: `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, cblf).commit();`

Comment: @JohnRannielSinel : In `CollegeBulletinListFragment ` class replace `android.app.Fragment` with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: Is it possible to do it using FragmentManagers? Instead of using supportmanagers?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the support library `android.support.v4...` for using `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: @Kevinrob  `getSupportFragmentManager()` is from `FragmentActivity` instead of `Fragment`.

Answer (score 2):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is defined on `AppCompatActivity` to avoid clashing with the native (non-support) `getFragmentManager()`. However, for the support `Fragment` class, there's no existing method to clash with, so you should instead use:

`getFragmentManager()`

to get the hosting `Activity`'s `FragmentManager`, or alternatively, use:

`getChildFragmentManager()`

to the the `Fragment`'s own `FragmentManager` (for nesting `Fragment`s)

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of `Fragment`, "regular", for which the import declaration is `android.app.Fragment`, and "support", which is `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Your `Fragment` isn't a "support" `Fragment`, evidenced by the `import declaration` in your code:

```
package com.example.navigationdrawerexample;

**import android.app.Fragment;**
import android.os.Bundle;
```

Second, you access `getSupportFragmentManager()` from a `FragmentActivity` (and thus any class that extends `FragmentActivity`, such as `ActionBarActivity` and `AppCompatActivity`)

So, to begin with, you should change your import declaration to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Then, you should ensure the `Activity` that hosts the `Fragment` is a `FragmentActivity` (or `AppCompatActivity` etc.)

Finally, inside your `Fragment`, you should be able to call `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`.

You can also browse the documentation for [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), as I would personally execute the code in your question from the `Activity`, not the `Fragment` itself, via an interface ([here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598968/view-pager-slide-to-next-page-programmatically-with-static-variable/33599233#33599233) to a related question that shows this technique).